# Mysql input ' (Apastrophe)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

So my code looks like this. If Submit is not successful I want that the text entered in form stays in form. But if I enter ' (apostrophe) in code and code is not successfully submited, input looks like this \' with a backslash.
. So what I get is. How\'s it going? I don't really want for input to display escape character. But I also need that mysql_real_escape_string so hackers won't hack my database. Please give me advice.

```
    <?php
      $title = sanitize($_POST['title']);
      $description = sanitize($_POST['description']);
    ?>
    <?php
      function sanitize($data) {
        return htmlentities(strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($data)));
       }
    ?>
    <form action="form.php" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
      <input type="text" name="title" class="text-3" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
      <textarea maxlength="1000" id="textarea" name="description" ><?php echo $description; ?></textarea><br>
      <input type="submit" value="8. Submit" id="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: I think just putting the `mysql_real_escape_string()` will do the trick.

Comment: Use stripslashes like  `echo stripslashes($title)` and mysql_* functions deprecated, try learning PDO, it will help your sanitizing problem too.

Comment: several of the mysql functions in php have been deprecated so it is unwise to reply upon these features for the future. The preferred  method now is to use PDO or perhaps even mysqli

Answer (score 0):

These 2 functions should handle (almost) everything between HTML and MySQL

When you want to output something in HTML, use `htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES)`

When you want to save something in DB, use `mysql_real_escape_string($value)`

As you can see there is the (almost) there, `mysql_real_escape_string` do not automatically escape `%` and `_` when you are using LIKE, you'll need to escape them manually by replace.